# Upload gcs files to google drive using airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-drive-shared-drive

Hi I am trying to upload a file from GCS to Gdrive using

```
airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_gdrive_operator import GcsToGDriveOperator
```

This is how the dag looks like

```
copy_to_gdrive = GcsToGDriveOperator(
    task_id="copy_to_gdrive",
    source_bucket="my_source_bucket_on_gcs",
    source_object="airflow-dag-test/report.csv",
    destination_object="/airflow-test/report.csv",
    gcp_conn_id="bigquery_default",
    dag=dag
)
```

This code executes without any errors and in the logs I can see the file is downloaded to local successfully and uploaded to gdrive successfully as well.

This code is executed by a service account, the issue i am facing is I am not able to find the file or the directory this dag is creating uploading

I have tried several permutation/combinations of path for "destination_object" but nothing seems to work also google docs are not helpful as well.

I can see in the api logs that that the drive.create api is being called but where it is creating the file is unknown. Has anyone experienced this ? any help or tip would be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Service account is a Google account, and, as google account, it has access to its own drive. The file are correctly copied to Drive, but to the drive of the service account!

*You never specify the account, so, how Airflow can know that it has to use yours?*

Look at the [operator documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gdrive_operator/index.html)

> delegate_to (str) – The account to impersonate, if any. For this to work, the service account making the request must have domain-wide delegation enabled.

Use this parameter, fill it with your email and activate the domain delegation wide to your service account.

Comment: Hey Guillaume, thanks for your response. I tried specifying the 'delegate_to' to my user and getting this error-- 'unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'  Have you come across anything similar? Could you share any example/sample code please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you grant service account token creator on your Airflow service account?

Comment: Hi,
I'm quite interested in the same issue. I understand your point but I find it a bit cumbersome to give the Composer service account the rights to impersonate my service account.
In the version I'm using https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/suite/transfers/gcs_to_gdrive/index.html, I only have the choice to use a impersonation_chain.
Is there no way I could rather create a Drive folder and share that folder with the composer service account instead (and write there) ?

Comment: P.S. Or perhaps it's already possible, but then how do I point to a shared folder in "destination_object"?